# Linux: how to mark a file descriptor as not inheritable on fork?

Tags: c, linux

Is it possible to mark a specific file descriptor as not inheritable, or close it, in the child process when `fork()` is invoked?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prevent file descriptors inheritance during Linux fork](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5713242/608639)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No. All file descriptors are inherited in fork. You can set a fd to be closed on exec, however, by using `fcntl(fd, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)`.

Comment: Also note that you can save the `fcntl` by passing `O_CLOEXEC` to `open` under Linux.

Comment: @Damon: Or any POSIX 2008 conformant system (`O_CLOEXEC` was standardized with POSIX 2008).

Answer (score 0):

No its not possible. By default child processes with inherit file table from parent process.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want close-on-fork, something like this could work:

```
static void fd_to_close;
static void closer()
{
    close(fd_to_close);
}

pthread_atfork(0, 0, closer);
```

Normally close-on-exec is the desired behavior anyway, though.