# Why doesn't O_CLOEXEC/FD_CLOEXEC flag work?

Tags: c, linux, pipe, fork, fcntl

I have a parent process having some children which don't need the FIFO descriptor opened by the parent before forking. I have tried to do the following approaches that

- `fcntl(fd, F_SETFD, fcntl(fd, F_GETFD) | FD_CLOEXEC);` after opening the fd.
- `fd = open(/tmp/testfifo, O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC|O_NONBLOCK);`

To see whether it works correctly I do following steps but the first one doesn't work since it is decided as [a bug](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=c6f3d81115989e274c42a852222b80d2e14ced6f). However, I don't understand what the wrong with the second is.

First approach,

```
if (fcntl(fd, F_GETFD) & FD_CLOEXEC) {
    fprintf(stderr, "FD_CLOEXEC is set\n");
}
```

Second approach over the terminal,

```
lsof -n | grep /private/tmp/testfifo
```

With two children it prints,

```
program   17898 soner    3r     FIFO     0t0 5274098 /private/tmp/testfifo
program   17898 soner    4w     FIFO     0t0 5274098 /private/tmp/testfifo
program   17899 soner    3r     FIFO     0t0 5274098 /private/tmp/testfifo
program   17899 soner    4w     FIFO     0t0 5274098 /private/tmp/testfifo
program   17900 soner    3r     FIFO     0t0 5274098 /private/tmp/testfifo
program   17900 soner    4w     FIFO     0t0 5274098 /private/tmp/testfifo
```

Is my approach wrong? Or did I do something wrong? Or did I misunderstand rationale of the flag?

Comment: Are you calling `exec()` in the child process?

Comment: @Barmar no sir, but what if even I call that? Assume that I've done the steps before exec.

Comment: `CLOEXEC` is short for "close on exec". It means the descriptor will be closed automatically when the process calls `exec()`. It's not closed when forking.

Comment: @Barmar so, do all children close it by calling _close()_? Isn't there another way?

Comment: Yes, that's what they normally do.

Comment: A (perhaps questionable) idiom I've seen used:  `if ((pid = fork()) != 0) { for (i=3;i<256;i++) close(i); }`

Comment: Related, see [Prevent file descriptors inheritance during Linux fork](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5713242/608639), [Why does closing file descriptors after fork affect the child process?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27483556/608639), [Close all File Handles when Calling posix_spawn](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21950549/608639), etc. The `posix_spawn` Q&A provides a very good sample that avoids closing `STDIN_FILENO` and friends if they are numbered in an unusual way.